# How to pass JSON object from Javascript to Python CGI script

Tags: javascript, python, json, cgi

I'm working on a python `CGI` script. A `JSON` file is hosted from the server. And I was able to get the data of the file as a `JSON` object. Now I need to pass this `JSON` object into a CGI script.

```
function cert_server() {
    var link = $("#link").val();
    var data;
    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

My JSON object is now stored in the variable "data". How could I pass it into a Python CGI ?

Comment: well the CGI script i assume is located on the server also...so you need to send the data to the correct URL (the URL which triggers the CGI script) using an AJAX request (assuming this JavaScript is browser based...if it's actually NodeJS then you can make a regular non-AJAX Http request). It's not clear though, if the JSON file and the CGI script are on the same server...could the CGI script not just read the JSON itself from the disk? You didn't entirely make the full situation apparent to us.

Comment: I have solved it by adding the content into a textfileld inside a form and send it to the CGI on submitting. Your support means a lot to me. Thank you so much @ADyson